# Excel workbook to outlook template

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, outlook

Please see attached image below for reference.

I have an excel workbook that i need to input data into every day on the fly. After inputting data i then need to re input the data into an outlook template and send it to clients.

My outlook template contains a basic table as seen in the picture.

What i want to do is after inputting the data into excel, click the button and it will automatically open the outlook template and fill in the data from the excel workbook ready to be sent.

I've been copying and pasting the data in but its starting to get out of hand because several hundred of these emails need to be done each day.

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

[image: View image here: Excel on the right, outlook template on the left]

Comment: does it have to be an HTML formatted message body?

Comment: As long as the table remains and the font type doesn't look like something from the 80's then it doesn't matter what format the email is in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I use for simple emails - pretty generic but you can tweak as you wish.

Select a row in your data and run the macro.  Adjust the HEADER_ROW and NUM_COLS constants to suit your layout.

```
Sub NotificationMail()

    Const HEADER_ROW As Long = 1 '<< the row with column headers
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 7   '<< how many columns of data

    Const olMailItem = 0
    Const olFolderInbox = 6

    Dim ol As Object, fldr, ns, msg
    Dim html As String, c As Range, colReq As Long, hdr As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ol = GetObject(, "outlook.application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ol Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ol = CreateObject("outlook.application")
        Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set fldr = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        fldr.display
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If ol Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't start Outlook to compose mail!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set msg = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Set rw = Selection.Cells(1).EntireRow

    msg.Subject = "Here's your information"

    html = "<style type='text/css'>"
    html = html & "body, p {font:10pt calibri;padding:40px;}"
    html = html & "table {border-collapse:collapse}"
    html = html & "td {border:1px solid #000;padding:4px;}"
    html = html & "</style>"

    html = html & "<p>Your request has been updated:</p>"
    html = html & "<table>"


    For Each c In rw.Cells(1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Cells
        If c.Column <> 4 Then '<<< EDIT to exclude ColD
            Set hdr = rw.Parent.Cells(HEADER_ROW, c.Column) '<< get the header text for this cell

            html = html & "<tr><td style='background-color:#DDD;width:200px;'>" & _
               hdr.Value & _
               "</td><td style='width:400px;'>" & Trim(c.Value) & "</td></tr>"
        End If 'we want this cell
    Next c

    html = html & "</table>"

    msg.htmlbody = html
    msg.display

End Sub
```

Comment: That is working great but is there any way to input the data without highlighting the row before running the code?

Comment: You don't have to highlight the row - it will pick up whichever row has the activecell.

Comment: Ok. 

1 more question. Is it possible to skip certain columns? Say for example i want data from a2,b2,c2,f2 but not d2?

Answer (score 0):

here is some code i have for reference

it shows how to create tables and how to address cells

has lot of extra stuff

just step through it

```
    Sub aTestEmail()

        Dim outMail As Outlook.mailItem
        Set outMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        outMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        outMail.Display (False)                      ' modeless

        Dim wd As Document
'       Set wd = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
        Set wd = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

'       wd.Range.InsertBreak 3    ' section (continuous)
'       wd.Range.InsertBreak 3    ' section (continuous)


        For i = 0 To 9
            wd.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
        Next

        debug_aTestEmail wd


        Stop

        Dim rng As Range

        Set rng = wd.Range(2, 8)
        rng.Select
        Debug.Print rng.Text
        rng.Collapse (1)  ' 0 - left, 1 - right
        rng.Select

        wd.Content.Select
 '       Debug.Print wd.Content.Text
 '       wd.Range(wd.Characters(104).End, wd.Characters(150).End).Select
 '       wd.Range(wd.Words(5).Start, wd.Words(10).Start).Select
 '       wd.Range(wd.Words(5).Start, wd.Words(10).End).Select
        wd.Range(wd.Words(5).End, wd.Words(10).End).Select




'        wd.Range.Select
'        wd.Sentences(1).Select
'        wd.Sentences(1).Words(1).Select
'        wd.Sentences(1).Words(5).Select
'        wd.Sentences(1).Words(10).Select


'        wd.Sentences(5).Characters(10).Select
'        wd.Sentences(5).Characters(10).Select
'        wd.Words(10).Select
'        wd.Words(11).Select
'        wd.Range.Words(10).Select
'        wd.Range.Words(11).Select

'        debug_aTestEmail wd
'        wd.Characters(4).Select

        wd.Tables.Add Range:=wd.Characters(8), NumRows:=5, NumColumns:=3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed

        wd.Tables.Add Range:=wd.Characters(3), NumRows:=5, NumColumns:=2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed

        wd.Tables(1).Range.Words(1).Select
        wd.Tables(1).Range.Words(2).Select

        wd.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells(1).Select
        wd.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells(2).Select
        wd.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells(3).Select
        wd.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells(4).Select
        wd.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells(5).Select


        Debug.Print wd.Sentences(1).Words.Count
        Debug.Print wd.Words.Count

        Dim tabl As Tables
        Set tabl = wd.Tables

        tabl(1).Style = "Grid Table 4 - Accent 3"  ' get this name from "table design" tab (hover over whichever style you like and a tool tip will give you the name)
'       tabl(1).ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
'       tabl(1).ApplyStyleLastRow = False
'       tabl(1).ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
'       tabl(1).ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
'       tabl(1).ApplyStyleRowBands = True
'       tabl(1).ApplyStyleColumnBands = False

        tabl(1).Range.InsertParagraph
        tabl(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.InsertParagraph
        tabl(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.InsertParagraph
        tabl(1).Cell(3, 1).Range.InsertParagraph


        tabl(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.InsertBefore "cell1"
        tabl(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.InsertBefore "cell2"
        tabl(1).Cell(3, 1).Range.InsertBefore "cell3"
        tabl(1).Cell(4, 1).Range.InsertBefore "cell4"
        tabl(1).Cell(5, 1).Range.InsertBefore "cell5"

        tabl(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.InsertBefore "cell6"
        tabl(2).Cell(2, 1).Range.InsertBefore "cell7"
        tabl(2).Cell(3, 1).Range.InsertBefore "cell8"
        tabl(2).Cell(4, 1).Range.InsertBefore "cell9"
        tabl(2).Cell(5, 1).Range.InsertBefore "cell10"


'        wd.Range.InsertBreak 3 ' section (continuous)
'        wd.Range.InsertBreak 3 ' section (continuous)

        debug_aTestEmail wd

'        wd.Sections(2).Range.InsertBefore ("before" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
'        wd.Sections(2).Range.InsertAfter ("after" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

'        debug_aTestEmail wd

'        wd.Sections(1).Range.Words(wd.Sections(1).Range.Words.Count).InsertBefore ("after1.1" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
'        wd.Sections(1).Range.Words(wd.Sections(1).Range.Words.Count).InsertBefore ("after1.2" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
'        wd.Sections(1).Range.Words(wd.Sections(1).Range.Words.Count).InsertBefore ("after1.3" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
'        wd.Sections(1).Range.Words(wd.Sections(1).Range.Words.Count).InsertBefore ("after1.4" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

'        For i = 1 To wd.Sections(1).Range.Words.Count
'            Debug.Print wd.Sections(1).Range.Words(i).Characters.Count & " ";
'            Debug.Print wd.Sections(1).Range.Words(i) & " "
'        Next


'        debug_aTestEmail wd

'        wd.Sections(2).Range.InsertAfter ("after2.1" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
'        wd.Sections(2).Range.InsertAfter ("after2.2" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
'        wd.Sections(2).Range.InsertAfter ("after2.3" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
'        wd.Sections(2).Range.InsertAfter ("after2.4" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

        Set wd = Nothing
        Set outMail = Nothing
    End Sub


    Sub debug_aTestEmail(wd As Document)

        Debug.Print "------------------------------------------------"
        Debug.Print "   wd.Sections.Count : " & wd.Sections.Count
        Debug.Print " wd.Paragraphs.Count : " & wd.Paragraphs.Count
        Debug.Print "  wd.Sentences.Count : " & wd.Sentences.Count
        Debug.Print "      wd.Words.Count : " & wd.Words.Count
        Debug.Print " wd.Characters.Count : " & wd.Characters.Count
        Debug.Print "        wd.Range.End : " & wd.Range.End
        Debug.Print "wd.StoryRanges.Count : " & wd.StoryRanges.Count
        Debug.Print "------------------------------------------------"

        Debug.Print wd.Tables.Count


    End Sub
```